# How to access bpy.props.StringProperty() from a different class?

Tags: python, add-on

I need to access the string in 'my_type' string property which reside in the class Append_OT_Operator from the class Apply_OT_Operator. How can I make this 'my_type' a variable that I can access globally? Or is there a better way?

This is my code in my_operators.py:

```
class Append_OT_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.appending_basic_objects"
    bl_label = "Append the basic objects"

    my_type : bpy.props.StringProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        path = (r'C:/Users/')
        blendfile = "Assets" + ".blend"

        bpy.ops.wm.append(
            filepath = blendfile,
            directory = path + '/' + blendfile + "/Object/",
            filename = self.my_type)   

        return {'FINISHED'}

class Apply_OT_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.apply"
    bl_label = "Apply most modifiers for UV unwrapping phase"

    def execute(self, context):

        print(my_type) #return an error, instead of printing my_type string
```

To clarify, 'my_type' is set when the user click on a button of the UI in my ui_panel.py:

```
class UI_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "UI_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "Bijoux Panel"
    bl_category = "Bijoux Addon"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('wm.appending_basic_objects', text = "append my_object1").my_type = 'my_object1'

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('wm.appending_basic_objects', text = "append my_object2").my_type = 'my_object2'
```

Answer (score 4):

**Window Manager keeps track of registered operators**

Lets say we add a property to the simple operator template, and make it register - undo

```
class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    xxx : bpy.props.StringProperty(default="foo")
```

Invoke it from the UI

[image: bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}]

Then in python console use `WindowManager.operator_properties_last`

```
>>> op = C.window_manager.operator_properties_last("object.simple_operator")
>>> op.xxx
'ggggg'
```

*Note the template class name is `SimpleOperator` but really should be `OBJECT_OT_simple_operator` to match its id name `"object.simple_operator"` as per the naming convention*

**Store in blend objects**

Alternatively store properties on ID objects in blender, eg scene, object, mesh etc.  Scene is often used as a "global".

```
from bpy.props import StringProperty

bpy.types.Scene.xxx = StringProperty()
```

set in an operator with

```
context.scene.xxx = self.my_string
```

retrieve with

```
print(context.scene.xxx)
```

layout with

```
layout.prop(context.scene, "xxx")
```

Comment: @RobertGützkow  Works without. Test with simple operator template.

Comment: I've tested it and only `C.window_manager.operator_properties_last("object.simple_operator")` works properly. `C.window_manager.operators['OBJECT_OT_simple_operator']` fails without `UNDO`. I think managing the state in the add-on yourself may be the cleaner solution.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, isn't there a more straightforward way? It feels like more of a workaround to my problem than a clean solution. Is there no way to declare a variable that is global to the whole addon? Also I'm really not sure how to include your solution to my code, you are talking about printing and using in layout and invoking from UI but this are all things that aren't connected to my questions from what I understand. Could be wrong though, if you could clarify/simplify your answer it would really help. Thanks again

Comment: Could be. I believe they are all connected to the question. Hence posting as an  answer. Pressing a button is "invoking from UI".  Used print as an example akn to `print(my_type)` in question.   A panel or operator has layout in its draw method. Re simple global eg adding a scene property, Seen in answer here too. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132944/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-bpy-types-operator-value  you may wsh to draw it in a panel.

Comment: I tried the first one-liner (bpy.types.Scene.xxx = StringProperty() ) in the console and get "NameError: name 'StringPropety' is not defined".

Comment: Need to import it first. (edited) Please  Notice the questioner has used `bpy.props.StringProperty`.  in question title..  Whereas I normally import as now shown.