# Accessing Transform Operator History inclusive constraint_axis in Python script

Tags: python, scripting, operator

Please have a look at this:

[image]

I am writing a script wich changes selected verts.

Lets say the user is in Box-select-mode (...or whatever tool), selects something, does some constrained transformation (example: Move in Z)

Now my script is changing the vertex selection.
At this point I want to reinvoke the constrained transformation (example: Move in Z).
The goal is, that the user doesn't have to hit G - Z (example) again but, the geometry sticks to the mouse and moves in Z until mouseclick.

What would be an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163129/how-can-i-access-view3d-select-circle-radius-value/163130#163130  and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132944/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-bpy-types-operator-value/159488#159488

Comment: As batFINGER mentioned, `bpy.context.window_manager.operators` and `...operator_properties_last` should be of use.