# Manually instantiate an operator?

Tags: python

Is there a useful way to manually create and initialize an instance operator class, such as would be done when running it?

A bunch of stuff would be easier to figure out if I could poke around inside an active operator object to see how it's structured.

Answer (score 1):

**`Operator.get_rna_type`**

This is not an instance of the operator, as documented it is an *"Internal function for introspection"*

for example the properties of the transform translate operator

```
>>> bpy.ops.transform.translate.get_rna_type(
get_rna_type(self)
Internal function for introspection
>>> rna = bpy.ops.transform.translate.get_rna_type()
>>> rna.properties['
                    constraint_axis']
                    cursor_transform']
                    gpencil_strokes']
                    mirror']
                    orient_matrix']
                    orient_matrix_type']
...

                    use_proportional_edit']
                    use_proportional_projected']
                    value']
```

Or directly after using the operator

```
>>> op = C.active_operator
>>> op
<bpy_struct, Operator("TRANSFORM_OT_translate") at 0x7f8cf52b8e88>
```

see also

[Is there a way to access a bpy.types.Operator value](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132944/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-bpy-types-operator-value)