# Set bpy.ops.render.render() write_still argument without launching

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

My problem is I had to write custom modal Render Animation operator for my add-on because using the original one together with my add-on crashes Blender. My operator makes some changes in the scene, changes the current frame, launches `bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', animation=False, write_still=True)`, waits until the render is finished with use of `bpy.app.handlers` - and repeats this process until all the frames in the scene are rendered. The operator itself works fine, but once `bpy.ops.render.render` is called with `write_still` == `True` Blender somehow stores this choice in the memory and the original Blender's `Render Image` button also starts to save the render result to the file after the render, although it should not by default. It is not so obvious and may ruin some user's progress so I would like to prevent it, if possible.

The question is - is there a way to set `bpy.ops.render.render()` `write_still` argument back to `False` without another unnecessary call of the render operator? I've been thinking of changing it directly somewhere in the `bpy.types.RENDER_OT_render.properties` but as you may know `bpy.ops.render.render()` is not a Python operator and it is not registered in `bpy.types`.

For now the only solution I see is to remember original Render Samples and Scene Resolution settings, render just 1 pixel with 1 sample with `write_still=False` and then set Scene settings back. But from my previous experience I know that such ultra-fast renders with changing Scene settings there and back may lead to crashes because of C internal errors which can not be handled from the Python API, and the probability is pretty high. So I hope there is a way to set `write_still` to `False` in some proper way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`WindowManager.operator_properties_last(...)`**

If the operator has been called previously to retrieve  the settings when last called

```
>>> props = C.window_manager.operator_properties_last("render.render")
>>> props
<bpy_struct, RENDER_OT_render at 0x7fe35d131fa8>

>>> props.write_still
True
```

If the operator has not been called, `props` will have value `None`

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> it uses this setting. Outputs to system console.

```
Saved: '/tmp/xxx.png'
 Time: 00:00.63 (Saving: 00:00.12)
```

Toggle

```
>>> props.write_still = False
```

press <kbd>F12</kbd> again and now it's off.

[How can I access view3d.select_circle radius value?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163129/how-can-i-access-view3d-select-circle-radius-value)

[Is there a way to access a bpy.types.Operator value](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132944/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-bpy-types-operator-value)

[Accessing Transform Operator History inclusive constraint_axis in Python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168702/accessing-transform-operator-history-inclusive-constraint-axis-in-python-script)

Comment: When this is done from inside the modal operator, right before `return {'FINISHED'}`, `write_still` in the scene becomes `True` again. I found out that this can be solved with adding a function to `depsgraph_update_post` handler which once sets `write_still` to `False` if it becomes `True` and removes itself from the handler.

Comment: also consider `render_complete` handler, (would normally say don't mix handlers and context .. the window manager is possibly one exception) ,  or via a `bpy.app.timer` as tacked on here to kill a draw callback  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/237437/15543

Comment: `write_still` in my operator changes after `render_complete`, so unfortunately it doesn't help, while `bpy.app.timers` should do the trick, although I haven't tested it yet.